# Sharepoint 2007 Survey creation customization issue

Tags: sharepoint-2007

When creating a Sharepoint 2007 survey, there is a possibility to show/hide the username of the user who took the survey.
Is it possible to set this option to No by default and make the selection read only?

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand you correctly that you want to change the default behavior of creating a survey list?

This is not easily done, because the survey list is based on the `SurveyList` list template and you would have to modify that one (if even possible) or create your own SurveyList template.

There are however tutorials on how to create a survey programmatically, which you could do with a Workflow and set your default properties for the survey list to hide usernames:

- [Creating a survey in MOSS 2007 programmatically](http://vspug.com/ssa/2006/11/03/creating-a-survey-in-moss-2007-programmatically/)
- [HowTo: Create a quizzing application with SharePoint 2007](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sridhara/archive/2008/12/15/howto-create-a-quizzing-application-with-sharepoint-2007.aspx)